# Simple compression algorithm

Tags: performance, c, security, compression, c99

An implementation of a simple compression algorithm that's featured in a programming practice book.

My goals:

1. **Robust**: All error conditions must be handled properly. The specification indicated in the self-documenting comment must be met exactly.
2. **Secure**: No opportunities for buffer overflow in the program.
3. **Efficient**: The implementation must be at most O(n) in time, be as efficient as possible in time, and result in using as little memory as possible.
4. **Compatible**: The implementation should be able to compile and run on any desktop, workstation, or server with a C99 compiler.
5. **Well documented**: The implementation should be clearly documented and re-usable.

Yes, this algorithm would probably never be used production. It was a test of my ability to write production quality C code. Is this efficient and secure C? Please provide any and all criticisms, including the way in which I documented the code.

a3compress.h:

```
#ifndef _A3COMPRESS_H_
#define _A3COMPRESS_H_
/* Compress an input string in the following manner:

   For each contiguous range of repeated chars, print the char followed by a
   decimal number indicating the number of repetitions.

   NOTE: 
       This function calls malloc, it returns NULL if malloc failed.
       In any other case the return value must be freed.

   Example:
       input: aaabbbbbccccaaa
       output: a3b5c4a3

   If the string contains a digit (0 - 9), the string will not be compressed,
   because the resulting compressed string would be ambiguous. A copy of the
   string is returned that must be freed.

   If the compressed string would not be of shorter length than the original
   string, a copy of the string is returned that must be freed. */
char * const a3compress (const char * const str);
#endif /* _A3COMPRESS_H_ */
```

a3compress.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "a3compress.h"

inline unsigned int count_digits (unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 0) {return 1;}

    unsigned int test = 1;
    unsigned int digits = 0;
    while (n >= test) {
        test *= 10;
        ++digits;
    } 

    return digits;
}

/* Compress an input string in the following manner:

   For each contiguous range of repeated chars, print the char followed by a
   decimal number indicating the number of repetitions.

   NOTE: 
       This function calls malloc, it returns NULL if malloc failed.
       In any other case the return value must be freed.

   Example:
       input: aaabbbbbccccaaa
       output: a3b5c4a3

   If the string contains a digit (0 - 9), the string will not be compressed,
   because the resulting compressed string would be ambiguous. A copy of the
   string is returned that must be freed.

   If the compressed string would not be of shorter length than the original
   string, a copy of the string is returned that must be freed. */
char * const a3compress (const char * const str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char * compressed;

    /* Determine the size of the compressed string */
    char curr = str[0];
    size_t cnt = 1;
    size_t idx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        /* If the current char is a decimal digit, abort. The compressed string
           would be ambiguous */
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {goto abort;}

        /* If the current char is the same as the previous char, and this
           isn't the last char in the input string, increase the count */
        if ((str[i] == curr) && (i != len - 1)) {
            ++cnt;
        } else {
            /* If this is the last char in the input string, increase the
               count */
            if (i == len - 1) {++cnt;}

            ++idx;
            if (idx > len - 1) {goto abort;} 

            /* Add the number of digits in the current count */
            size_t digits = count_digits(cnt);
            idx += digits;
            if (idx > len - 1) {goto abort;} 

            /* Begin counting repeats of the newly seen char */
            curr = str[i];
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }

    compressed = (char *)malloc((idx + 1) + 1);
    if (compressed == NULL) {return compressed;}

    curr = str[0];
    cnt = 1;
    idx = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        /* If the current char is the same as the previous char, and this
           isn't the last char in the input string, increase the count */
        if ((str[i] == curr) && (i != len - 1)) {
            ++cnt;
        } else {
            /* If this is the last char in the input string, increase the
               count */
            if (i == len - 1) {++cnt;}

            /* Add the current char to the output string */
            compressed[idx++] = curr;

            /* Add the current count to the output string */
            size_t digits = count_digits(cnt);
            char digit_s[digits + 1];
            size_t digit_len = snprintf(digit_s, digits + 1, "%d", 
                                        (unsigned int)cnt);
            idx += strlcpy(&compressed[idx], digit_s, digit_len + 1);

            /* Begin counting repeats of the newly seen char */
            curr = str[i];
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }

    return compressed;

abort:
    compressed = (char *)malloc(len + 1);
    if (compressed == NULL) {return compressed;}
    strlcpy(compressed, str, len + 1);
    return compressed;
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a3compress.h"

int main (const int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;
    linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin);
    if (linelen <= 0) {perror(NULL), exit(1);}
    if (line[linelen - 1] == '\n') {line[linelen - 1] = '\0';}

    char * const compressed = a3compress(line);
    if (compressed == NULL) {perror(NULL), exit(1);}
    free(line);
    printf("%s\n", compressed);
    free(compressed);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a variant of [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Is there a reason to re-invent the wheel? Generally, trying to roll your own compression, hash or encryption algorithm is a bad idea since chances are very slim that you can improve on the existing stuff unless you're an expert in that field. But chances are high you're making something inefficient/insecure.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I've overlooked your _"It was a test of my ability to write production quality C code."_ statement.

Comment: Better algorithm `<char Sequence => '<char><count>'+` Where `<count>` is an actual number (not the text version of a number), remember that a char is just a very small integer (8 bits). Because you are using the text representation of a number you are using 8bits to represent 4 1/2 bits so you are wasting a lot of bits. There is a limit since a char can hold 0-256 this encoding breaks into sequence that are a max of 256 characters long: But 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' => 'AA' (A is the 65 character so that). This also allows number to be encoded.

Comment: Note: Compressed text is usually not human readable so where `<count>` is a non printable character it does not really matter.

Answer (score 6):

## Comments

The `count_digits` function could need an explanation (what is its purpose?).

A lot of your comments describe what the code does. This is redundant, I can read the code to see what your code is doing. Instead, a comment should describe *why* something is done or *why* something is done in this specific way.

For example, the comment *"If this is the last char in the input string, increase the count"* is not very helpful. I can see that the code is doing that, but the question is: why is count increased only for the last character?

## malloc

[Don't cast the `malloc` return type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Also, why `malloc((idx + 1) + 1)` ? Why not `+2`, and what's the reason for adding 2 in the first place? It needs a comment.

## Logic

You're not handling an empty string correctly. You'll allocate 3 bytes instead of 1 byte and won't assign the 0 termination, which might lead to crashes or at least funny garbage when printing.

## Return value

In case something is wrong (like invalid input string `123`) you return a copy of the original string. But this is likely to be invalid or nonsense input for your decompression. So you can't distinguish between a valid and invalid return value. I would expect to have `NULL` returned on error and `errno` set to a reasonable value like `EINVAL`.

## Standard conformance

`strlcpy` is a BSD function and probably not available everywhere. Since you've explicitly listed "compability" and only mentioned C99, you might want to use `strncpy` instead. But be careful to correctly append the 0 termination (see also the problem with the empty string).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It was interesting to read Ulrich Drepper's opinion on `strlcpy`

Comment: `strlcpy` and `strncpy` only have comparable behavior by happenstance when the buffer is exactly one element longer than the source-string. So no, don't use them as replacements for each other.

Answer (score 6):

**A few notes:**

- You use `size_t` everywhere else in your program besides in `count_digits()` where you use `unsigned int`.  I would switch over and use `size_t` for consistency and to get rid of the compiler warnings.  If you have a reason not to, you should leave some sort of comment stating why.
- You do not modify the parameter passed to `count_digits`, so it should be declared as `const`.
- If you want to, you could "simplify" your `while` loops into a `for` loop.

  > ```
  > while (n >= test) {
  >     test *= 10;
  >     ++digits;
  > }
  > ```

  How I might do it (up to your discretion on whether or not you want to do this or not):

  ```
  for (; n >= test; digits++)
  {
      test *= 10;
  }
  ```
- Cast `cnt` into a `size_t` for consistency:

  ```
  size_t digit_len = snprintf(digit_s, digits + 1, "%zu", (size_t) cnt);
  ```
- You are inconsistent on where you put your `const`

  > ```
  > int main (const int argc, char * const argv[])
  > ```

  Either always put it before you declare the type, or after.
- You should always initialize your variables when you declare them.  I noticed specifically the variable `compressed`.

---

## TL;DR:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. By the way, `const char * const argv[]` is not the same as `char * const argv[]`. The former means that both the pointers and their contents must not be modified, the latter means that only the pointers must not be modified. When I wrote `char * const argv[]`, it means that the contents of arguments may be modified, but the pointers must not, this was my intention.

Comment: @OregonTrail Agreed, but like I stated: consistency is key.  If you deviate from your consistency than you need to state why in a comment.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that appropriate use of `const` to indicate whether a pointer is `const` or its content is `const` is a matter of consistency. It has self-documenting semantics.

Comment: @OregonTrail To a beginner, I don't think they would be able to read that self-documentation.  You should always leave code in a highly understandable and maintainable state as possible.  If you were to leave this code in the hands of a programmer still getting their grips on the language, I would highly doubt they would know the difference between `const` indicating if the pointer or the content is `const`.  It's up to you to make the changes, but that's my opinion on it.

Comment: This would mean adding an explanation above every signature for `main` that I write, which I don't intend to adopt. A comment explaining the syntax of the language is unnecessary, like writing the comment `x = ++i; /* increments i, then stores the result in x */`

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. Even if someone knew the meaning of my `main` signature, I should explain why I choose to allow modification of the arguments but not their location.

Comment: @OregonTrail Exactly.  I kinda had a bit of trouble getting that across, didn't I? :P

Comment: Well, I kind of side-tracked you by mixing the concept of meaning with intention.

Answer (score 3):

A few comments.

- Your function does more or less the same thing twice.  If you want to do that, then I would seperate the two halves into functions.  But actually I would instead just allocate memory of the same length as the input string and encode into it.  You can then call `realloc` at the end to recover wasted memory, if necessary.
- You have duplicated the description of the function.  Either put it in the
  header or in the C file.  If you put it in both the descriptions will
  diverge over time.
- I don't see why the function must return a `const` string.
- Your `count_digits` should be `static` not `inline`.  Whether to `inline`
  can be decided better by the compiler.
- Use `isdigit` to detect numeric chars
- Your comments are rather noisy - conveying little of use.  If you use
  functions the code becomes self documenting - eg if your code that does the
  "Add the current count to the output string" was extracted to a function
  named `add_count` with the string and number as parameters it would be 
  obvious what it was doing without a comment.

Here is how I might approach the function (not tested)

```
char* a3compress (const char* const s)
{
    const size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *res = calloc(len + 1, 1);
    if (res) {
        char *comp = res;
        for (int span = 1, n = 0; n < len; n += span) {

            if (isdigit(s[n])) { /* digits confuse the string encoding */
                memcpy(res, s, len + 1);
                break;
            }
            *comp++ = s[n];
            span = char_span(s, s[n]);
            if (span > 1) {
                comp += write_char_count(comp, span);
            }
        }
        assert(comp <= res + len);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The two functions do the obvious things.  The `assert` is a sanity check -the logic of the function doesn't allow the assertion to fail, but the coding might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`count_digit()` has trouble with `n` near `UINT_MAX` as `test *= 10` can overflow.  Further, a special `if (n == 0)` is not needed.

```
#define MAXUPOWER10 1000000000u
#define MAXUPOWER10LOG 9

inline unsigned count_digits(unsigned n) {
    if (n >= MAXUPOWER10) 
      return MAXUPOWER10LOG + 1;
    unsigned test = 1;
    for (unsigned digits = 1; ; digits++) {  // or do loop
        test *= 10;
        if  (n < test) break; 
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Certain other algorithmic simplifications possible.